# TTF/OTF fonts on xlib

Tags: c++, fonts, xlib, truetype, opentype

I'm Doing some simple tests with XLIB and c++ on linux, and I was wondering, is there any (relatively easy) way to implement OTF and TTF fonts in Xlib. Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: I'd simply like fonts. I'll take out the smoothing part

Comment: when you say implement, do you mean "create them from scratch", or just "load fonts that you have on disk"? Because if the latter, that is quite easily found with a websearch (e.g. second hit on google for me is https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/font-metrics/fonts.html)

Comment: I pretty much meant load from disk, and Nim pretty much hit that right on the head. Thank you for the link, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, opentype and unicode are tentacular specs, you need to use specialized libs such as (harfbuzz-ng + freebidi + fontconfig + freetype) to get something that works in anything but trivial cases.

The font handling bits in Xlib are legacy leftovers of the time when XFree86 people thought modern fonts would be "easy". It proved a lot harder, and later versions of this code were spun out in separate projects that eventually became the libs I pointed to.